# WebSecurity Compile time error

Tags: asp.net

I am registering user for this i initialize my database in HttpGet  method but i am facing this error

> The name websecurit does not exis in current context asp

Here is my code.

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Registeration()
{
  if (!WebSecurity.Initialized)
  {
    WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("MVCLoginConStr", "Authentication", 
      "UserId", "FirstName", autoCreateTables: true);
  }

  return View();
}
```

Comment: The code and error message doesn't match. The error message looks like there is a typo: `websecurit`, but the code is correctly spelt. Please copy-paste your exact code and error message.

Comment: Possibly duplicate [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17596944/](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17596944/websecurity-does-not-exist-in-the-current-context-error-in-appstart-cshtml)